# Snappy not linking with rust

Tags: rust, snappy

I was trying to follow the [ffi](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html) example in the Rustnomicon.
I cloned the snappy repository and built it. I placed the snappy library inside the targets/debug/deps/ directory. Here is the code -

```rust
use libc::size_t;

#[link(name = "snappy", kind="static")]
extern "C" {
    fn snappy_max_compressed_length(source_length: size_t) -> size_t;
}

fn main() {
    let x = unsafe { snappy_max_compressed_length(100) };
    println!("max compressed length of a 100 byte buffer: {}", x);
}
```

When I try to build it, it fails with this error -

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
          snappy.lib(snappy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPEAX_K@Z)
          snappy.lib(snappy-stubs-internal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter
          snappy.lib(snappy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPEAX_K@Z)
          snappy.lib(snappy-stubs-internal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport
          C:\Users\HP\Desktop\rust\c_interop\target\debug\deps\c_interop.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Hit the same issue. Can somebody help? Thanks.